# Mobile Payment Library issue in transferring money

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have downloaded `MPL SDK` and tested the sample project, in `PayPal` sandbox mode, that comes with [SDK](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL).

There is one issue I face with it. When money is transferred from any account to `US` account holder then it works fine. But when `US` account holder sends money to any `non-US` account holder then money is **deducted from sender's account** but **not transferred to receiver's account**. Also please note that in this case it says **payment successful**.

Has anyone use `MPL` for payment using `PayPal` and facing the same issue? I have used sandbox, so is it the case with production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the account receiving the money is liable to so. Note that not all PayPal users from all countries are able to receive funds on their account. Details for this can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/)

Comment: Please consider unvoting this answer if it has helped you. Otherwise I would more than happy to offer you more help :)